# Making PyQt QRadiobutton across multiple layout exclusive

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qradiobutton

I am trying to create radio buttons with only one being active at any one time. I have tried using the QButtonGroup and setting it Exclusive. However it doesn't seem to work. My code is as below:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import sys
class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        button_group = QtGui.QButtonGroup()
        data_list = ['apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'mango']
        main_widget = QtGui.QWidget()
        main_widget_layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        main_widget.setLayout(main_widget_layout)
        for item in data_list:
            radio_button = QtGui.QRadioButton()
            button_group.addButton(radio_button)
            item_label = QtGui.QLabel(item)
            mini_widget = QtGui.QWidget()
            mini_widget_layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
            mini_widget_layout.addWidget(radio_button)
            mini_widget_layout.addWidget(item_label)
            mini_widget_layout.addStretch(True)
            mini_widget.setLayout(mini_widget_layout)
            main_widget_layout.addWidget(mini_widget)
        button_group.setExclusive(True)
        self.setCentralWidget(main_widget)
        self.show()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_window = Window()
    main_window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

However, when I tried to add the same radio buttons on the single layout as below, the radio buttons are exclusive and only active one at a time.

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import sys

class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        data_list = ['apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'mango']
        main_widget = QtGui.QWidget()
        main_widget_layout = QtGui.QFormLayout()
        for item in data_list:
            radio_button = QtGui.QRadioButton()
            main_widget_layout.addRow(radio_button,QtGui.QLabel(item))

        main_widget.setLayout(main_widget_layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(main_widget)
        self.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_window = Window()
    main_window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

How do I make my radio buttons exclusive and active one at a time if they are in the different layouts as shown in my first code example?

Answer (score 1):

You are only making a temporary `ButtonGroup` which gets destroyed at the end of `__init__`. Make the `ButtonGroup` a member of your class to fix this.
The call `button_group.setExclusive(True)` is not needed as this is already the default for a `ButtonGroup`. I also check the first button explicitly because otherwise the `ButtonGroup` is in an unkown state.

Fixed code:

```
class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.button_group = QtGui.QButtonGroup()
        data_list = ['apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'mango']
        main_widget = QtGui.QWidget()
        main_widget_layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        main_widget.setLayout(main_widget_layout)
        first = True
        for item in data_list:
            radio_button = QtGui.QRadioButton()
            if first:
                radio_button.setChecked(True)
                first = False
            self.button_group.addButton(radio_button)
            item_label = QtGui.QLabel(item)
            mini_widget = QtGui.QWidget()
            mini_widget_layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
            mini_widget_layout.addWidget(radio_button)
            mini_widget_layout.addWidget(item_label)
            mini_widget_layout.addStretch(True)
            mini_widget.setLayout(mini_widget_layout)
            main_widget_layout.addWidget(mini_widget)
        self.setCentralWidget(main_widget)
        self.show()
```

Comment: Please let me know if this worked for you and mark the answer as accepted if it indeed solved your problem.